# ActivityIndicator without dialog box on android?

Tags: titanium

Im new to titanium and i'm trying to create an a indeterminate preloader (or activity indicator as it is called in titanum). The problem is that on android, the activty indicator is automatically placed in a dialog box, preventing users from interacting with the app until the dialog is dismissed.

Is there any way to just add a simple indetermindate preloader without using a dialog box in android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Appcelerator Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator-property-cancelable)

> Activity indicators must be used differently on Android and iOS:
>
> On Android, the activity indicator is a modal dialog that blocks the UI. Calling show displays the indicator, and calling hide removes it.

One option that you can use is setting cancelable property to true which let the user to cancel the activity indicator dialog by pressing the BACK button.

Appcelerator docs says :

> An activity indicator can be used to show the progress of an operation
>   in the UI to let the user know that some action is taking place. An
>   activity indicator consists of a spinning animation and an optional
>   text message, and is used to indicate an ongoing activity of
>   indeterminate length. To show progress, use ***Titanium.UI.ProgressBar***
>   instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Titanium.App.addEventListener('show_indicator', function(e) {

showIndicator(e.title_msg, e.sub_msg);
});

function showIndicator(title_msg, sub_msg) {

    var actIndG = Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator({
        style : Titanium.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.BIG,
        top :10
        left : 130,
        height : 60,
        width : 60,
        height : screenheigth,
        width : screenwidth

    });
    indView.add(actIndG);
    indWin.open();
 }
```

Up vote or Mark best if it helps you.